# How to make Java class know what to extend?

Tags: java, class, extends

Assume we have three classes, `Parent`, `Child1 extends Parent implements ISomething` and `Child2 extends Parent implements ISomethingElse`. Now, I want to make `Child3`, which will either `extends` `Child1` or `Child2` depending on what `Child3` receives.

The `Child3` constructor is something like this:

```
public <T extends Parent> Child3(T child) {}
```

How can I make `Child3` know which class to extend?
(Don't answer `Parent`. Assume extending `Parent` will break the code and `Parent` doesn't implement anything)

Comment: Sounds like you want a "creational pattern". Common examples are `Builder`, `Factory`, `AbstractFactory`, etc.

Comment: This is not possible in Java. Consider defining classes `Child3` and `Child4` that extend `Child1` and `Child2` respectively. If you need to create objects of these classes dynamically define a factory method that either returns an instance of one or the other.

Comment: But what if I need to override a method from `Parent` in `Child3`? Is there a way to override a method from different classes?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned ISomething and ISomethingElse. Which indicates that you want different **features, capabilities**, possibly combined, for Child classes.

In that case inheritance is unsuitable.

```
class Parent {

    // Untyped but safe.
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> capabilities = new HashMap<>();

    protected <I> void register(Class<I> intf, I obj) {
        capabilities.put(intf, obj);
    }

    public <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> intf) {
        Object obj = capabilities.get(intf);
        return obj == null ? Optional.emtpy() : Optional.of(intf.cast(obj));
    }
}

interface Flying {
    void fly(double altitude);
}

Parent pelican = new Pelican();
Flying flying = pelical.lookup(Flying.class).orElse(null);
flying.fly(0.5);

pelical.lookup(Swimming.class).ifPresent(
    swimming -> swimming.swim(true);
);

class Bird extends Parent { ... } // With Swimming capability

class Pelican extends Bird {

    public Pelican() {
        register(Swimming.class -> new Swimming() {
            @Override public void swim(boolean atSurface) { ... }
        });
    }
}
```

This is more versatile and more dynamic. But one might want:

```
class Pelican extends Bird implements Swimming {

    @Override
    public void swim(boolean atSurface) {
        return lookup(Swimming.class).get().swim(atSurface);
    }
}
```

In your case, you seem to want an object either has ISomething or ISomethingElse, so this would be a solution.

If all this seems too much overhead, consider **delegation**:

```
class Pelican extends Bird implements Swimming {
    private final Swimming swimmer = new SwimmingImplemetation(this);

    @Override
    public void swim(boolean atSurface) {
        return swimmer.swim(atSurface);
    }
}
```

Pelican actually delegates to a Swimming implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Inheritance structure are defined at compile time (unless you use magic).

You have to create two classes and replace your constructor with factory method (or pair of factory methods).

PS: You may consider replacing inheritance with delegation if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer composition over inheritance:

```
public class Parent {}

public interface ISomething {}

public interface ISomethingElse {}

public class Child1 extends Parent implements ISomething {}

public class Child2 extends Parent implements ISomethingElse {}

// Child 3 does not inherits from other classes
public class Child3<T extends Parent> {
    
    private final T child;
    
    public Child3(T child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
    
    public T getChild() {
        return this.child;
    }
}

// Consumer checks type of contained value.
// If you dont want to check types you can
// create adapter classes for each subclass of parent
public class Consumer {
    
    public void test(Child3 child3) {
        
        if (child3.getChild() instanceof Child1) {
            final Child1 child1 = (Child1) child3.getChild();
        }
        if (child3.getChild() instanceof Child2) {
            final Child2 child2 = (Child2) child3.getChild();
        }
    }
}
```