# Using Bifunction in enum with runtime polymorphism

Tags: java, generics, enums, functional-interface

I would like to implement runtime polymorphism using Enum and BiFunction. Below are my sample code snippet.

```
public interface Animal {
}

public interface Birds extends Animal {
    boolean canFly(AnimalDetails animalDetails);
}

public interface Dog extends Animal {
    boolean canBark(AnimalDetails animalDetails);
}

enum AnimalTypes {
    CAN_BARK(Dog::canBark),
    CAN_FLY(Birds::canFly);
    private final BiFunction<Animal, AnimalDetails, Boolean> typeAlgo;
    AnimalTypes(BiFunction<Animal, AnimalDetails, Boolean> typeAlgo) {this.typeAlgo = typeAlgo;}
}
```

So, at runtime I would like to pass Dog/Birds class object by casting into Animal class.
But, enum's constructor is showing **Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context** as compile time error.

If I move all the methods from Dog and Birds to Animal class and pass BiFunction's first argument as Animal then it works correctly.

Any suggestions/alternative solutions to achieve runtime polymorphism using enum and BiFunction would be appreciated.

Comment: Enum values all have the same type, and so cannot be generic. If you want values with differing types, you need to define and implement an interface. Depending on what you're looking to do, you can emulate enums to an extent, e.g. non-instantiability via a private ctor.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407989/984823  With something like `animal.lookup(Flying.class).fly();`

Comment: @Sweeper, I am developing an application in which application API will receive Object Type (Birds, Dog, etc) and method name (CAN_FLY,CAN_BARK, etc) which needs to be executed and return the value.
I am using this approach so that, in future if I would like to add new Type with new method then I just need to create an Interface which will be extended by an Animal interface and make an entry into AnimalTypes enum.
This will allow me to ignore if-else block for searching and executing that particular method on a specific type.

Comment: "*...and make an entry into AnimalTypes enum*" lets stop for a minute. Idea behind enums is that it contains *fixed* amount of known values. Imagine we have `enum MyEnum{ A,B;}` and few `switch` which handle *all* values, like `switch(myEnum){ case A -> foo(); case B -> bar();}`. Now when we add new value `C` compiler will *not* warn us about unhandled case C. This means we need to remember to find and fix all such places. It may not be big risk if enum is used only by you. But can it be used by others? If yes their switch code may be broken, since it won't handle all values when it should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a generic type on the enum constant, though Java doesn't currently allow it and this seems not to change in the future as the [JEPS 301](https://openjdk.org/jeps/301) has been closed and withdrawn.

Here is a full discussion: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8170351

**Verbose workaround:**

You can create a wrapper for your animal `BiFunction` that makes a decision based on casting whether the wrapped `BiFunction` shall be used for evaluation or a default value (`null` makes sense in this context as long as `Boolean` is used to distinguish from `false` returned from an Animal-specific implementation) is returned directly.

```java
class AnimalBiFunction<T extends Animal> implements BiFunction<T, AnimalDetails, Boolean> {

    private final Class<T> type;
    private final BiFunction<T, AnimalDetails, Boolean> delegate;

    // all-args constructor

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(T t, AnimalDetails details) {
        try {
            return delegate.apply(type.cast(t), details);
        } catch (ClassCastException ignore) {}
        return null; // default value
    }
}
```

The trick is that the generic types are allowed for the scope of the individual methods or constructor in the `enum`, although the `enum` itself cannot be generic. Just wrap the type-specific function into the wrapper. For easy usage, I also recommend `AnimalClass` implementing `BiFunction<Animal, AnimalDetails, Boolean>` itself and delegating the call to the encapsulated function.

```java
enum AnimalTypes implements BiFunction<Animal, AnimalDetails, Boolean> {

    CAN_BARK(new AnimalBiFunction<>(Dog.class, Dog::canBark)),
    CAN_FLY(new AnimalBiFunction<>(Birds.class, Birds::canFly));

    private final AnimalBiFunction<Animal> delegate;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T extends Animal> AnimalTypes(final AnimalBiFunction<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = new AnimalBiFunction<>(
                Animal.class,
                (BiFunction<Animal, AnimalDetails, Boolean>) delegate
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(final Animal animal, final AnimalDetails details) {
        return delegate.apply(animal, details);
    }
}
```

Finally, the application is quite straightforward. Here is a minimal sample:

```java
final Birds birds = details -> true;
final Dog dog = details -> true;
final Dog cat = details -> false;  // dumb example, but something to yield false

// Birds
System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_BARK.apply(birds, null));    // null
System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_FLY.apply(birds, null));     // true

// Dog
System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_BARK.apply(dog, null));      // true
System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_FLY.apply(dog, null));       // null

System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_BARK.apply(cat, null));      // false
System.out.println(AnimalTypes.CAN_FLY.apply(cat, null));       // null
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas, with this approach for every method call we need to create multiple instances of AnimalBiFunction.

Comment: @sushil: You'd do it anyway if the generics type on enums would be allowed. With my solution, you use a wrapper around it.